# Making GCC 5.1.0 work with CUDA 7.5 as non-root user

Tags: c++, c++11, cuda, gcc5, limited-user

I've done the rounds through Google unsuccessfully. My question is a bit unique - I have a big chunk of code that has a lot of C++11 dependencies, which runs just fine when I compile with GCC 5.1.0 but throws a big bunch of errors on GCC 4.8.3, the latter which works fine with CUDA. I also need to do some work with CUDA, which of course doesn't work because of the GCC 5.1.0 version. This is similar to a number of issues raised before, whose recommendations involved editing the host_config.h file to remove the offending line. However, I'm working on an institution's cluster and cannot edit the file since it was installed by the Sys admin. I can load any GCC version using the module load command but we have the C++11 dependency issues with the code if I downgrade to a lower GCC version. Any advice around this?

Comment: Make a local copy of the CUDA 7.5 toolkit and edit `host_config.h` and use nvcc from the local copy ?

Comment: @Pavan Yalamanchili Thanks for the quick reply. Am I to do a simple copy-paste operation of the CUDA toolkit? Anyway, let me try it out.

Comment: Use rsync if it is available instead of copy. rsync avoids copying duplicates for symbolic links.

Comment: @Pavan Yalamanchili It seems to still reference the system installed version. I'm using Cmake with find_package(CUDA).. Maybe I need to do something to make it reference the copy in my home dir? How do I do so? Or rather, how should I write my Cmake to consider the changes?

Comment: You need to export the environment variable `CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR` to the new path and start over again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming related.

Comment: You may also want to try [CUDA 8 Release Candidate](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Pavan Yalamanchili. Copying of the system installed version to a local path allowed me to edit the host_config file, thereby resolving the issue.